# Getting original filename from Jenkins pipeline file upload

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am creating a Jenkins pipeline job that asks for a file from user to upload.
Here is the snippet:

```
stage('Upload a file') {
        def inFile = input id: 'file1', message: 'Upload a file', parameters: [file(name: 'data.tmp', description: 'Choose a file')]
        sh "echo \\\"Uploaded ${inFile}\\\"" 
}
```

When I uploaded a zip file "data123.zip", this original filename is lost and is renamed to "data.tmp", which is what I obtain from the variable `inFile`.

Other things that I tried that didn't work (I know some of them are silly):

1. `${inFile.remote}`
2. `file(name: '')`
3. `file(description: '')`
4. `${file1}`

Do you know if it's possible to get the original filename when uploading a file using Jenkins pipeline input step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't do this right now.

See this code in Jenkins - the original file name is simply not available in the `FilePath` object that gets returned by the `input` step: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-input-step-plugin/blob/41d514d266722433181e860d8cf90d56bca5046e/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/input/InputStepExecution.java#L385